# Why does CSS text-decoration underline leads to different Baselines?

Tags: html, css

When use **text-decoration: underline** for links that are hover like this:

```
a:HOVER {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This means that the text that is part of a link will be set above the baseline compared to normal text. See the following image to see this problem.

[image]

The blue text is the link and the gray text is a normal span element. The blue text is above the baseline.

**How can I achieve to set them on the same baseline?**

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true: [http://jsfiddle.net/we32a/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/we32a/1/). You probably have other CSS differences between the two elements, besides the `text-decoration`.

Comment: this behavior involves CSS like display, font-family, line-height or whatever set hover, earlier or above(heavier) the basic rules. not enough information to give you any correct tips